# PySpark. Correlation between spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead and spark.executor.pyspark.memory

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I faced with an issue when serving ml model using PySpark 2.4.0 and MlFlow.

Executor fails with the following exception:

`org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Memory was leaked by query. Memory leaked: (2048) Allocator(stdin reader for ./my-job-impl-condaenv.tar.gz/bin/python) 0/2048/8194/9223372036854775807 (res/actual/peak/limit)`

From the articles about PySpark, I understood the following things:

1. spark runs at least one python process for each core of each executor;
2. `spark.executor.memory` parameter configures only JVM memory limits and doesn't affect the python process;
3. python worker process consumes memory from executor overhead, configured using `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`;
4. since spark 2.4.0 we can reserve memory for python worker explicitly using `spark.executor.pyspark.memory` that allows us to plan memory more granularly and stop overcommitting memory using `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`;

Here is an explanation of `spark.executor.pyspark.memory` from official docs:

> The amount of memory to be allocated to PySpark in each executor, in MiB unless otherwise specified. If set, PySpark memory for an executor will be limited to this amount. If not set, Spark will not limit Python's memory use and it is up to the application to avoid exceeding the overhead memory space shared with other non-JVM processes. When PySpark is run in YARN or Kubernetes, this memory is added to executor resource requests.

At first, I just increased the amount of memory using `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` and error finally gone.

Then I decided to make things better and specify the amount of memory for python worker using `spark.executor.pyspark.memory` that caused to the same error.

So, seems that I didn't properly understood what exactly configures `spark.executor.pyspark.memory` and how it correlates with `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`

I don't have too much experience with PySpark, so I hope that you'll help me to understood the process of memory allocation in PySpark, thx !